# SocketAsyncEventArgs and mixed Async and Sync calls to Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, socketasynceventargs

Is it possible to call saea.AcceptSocket.Send after a saea.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync has been completed? (saea == SocketAsyncEventArgs)

Is it ok to call saea.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync again after calling saea.AcceptSocket.Send?

Actually I want my receiving to be Asyn and my sending (which is 1/10000 compared to receives) to be Sync.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mix sync and async access to your socket.
I think you should even be able to send data while receiving data (or waiting for data to arrive).